# Is it possible to define Type, Labels and Id of Node and Relationship with Neo4Jclient?

Tags: neo4jclient

In a browser I can do some command with Cypher to define a Type, Label and Id of Nodes and Relationships like:

```
    MATCH (a)-[r]-(b) RETURN Id(a), Labels(a), Type(r), a
```

Are there ways to do this in Neo4jclient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question shows *querying* this information, not defining it.

You can write an equivalent query with Neo4jClient like so:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(a)-[r]-(b)")
    .Return(a => new {
        Id = a.Id(),
        Labels = a.Labels(),
        Type = r.Type()
    })
```

Functions are documented here: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher#using-functions-in-return-clauses